# scanning through an excel column to search ID

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an ID from a list box and then scanning through an excel sheet (ID) to find out if that ID exists or not. If it doesn't I have to add it in the end. If it does, I have to find out which row that ID is present.

I am looping this way

```
 count = 1
 count1=1

 While (Worksheets("ID").Cells(Count, 1) <> "")
     If StrComp(Worksheets("ID").Cells(Count, 2), list1.Value, vbTextCompare = 1) Then
         count1=count
 count = count +1
```

Comment: Are you looking for a single or multiple results? And in a particular column of "ID"?

Comment: The Fields in first column of sheet ID should match with ID listed in list box. Single results. The ID's are unique.

Comment: Is your listbox on a UserForm?

Comment: Its on the excel spread sheet as an activeX control

Comment: With a little formatting (thx Slaks) and two minor clarifications the question was readily answerable RBarryYoung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using FInd to look at column B for a single case-insenstive match on the whole string, ie

Update: If you were running the find from the active X control directly then:

```
    Private Sub List1_Click()
 Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Sheets("ID").Columns("B").Find(List1.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole, , False)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox List1.Value & " found at " & rng1.Row
    Else
        MsgBox List1.Value & " not found"
    End If
End Sub
```